# Excepciones Python

Tags: python, funciones, excepciones, programación-funcional, números-enteros

Estoy intentando resolver este problema:

> 1.-Defina dos excepciones “MuyAlto” y “MuyBajo”. Escriba una función que  tome un parámetro N y que lance la excepción “MuyAlto”
> cuando N sea mayor  de 50 y “MuyBajo” cuando N sea menor que 10.
> En otro caso mostrará por  pantalla el valor de N.
>
> 2.-comprobar que N es un entero y lanzar la excepción  TypeError en caso de que no sea así.

Para el primer punto hice esto ,lo cual funciona:

```
    def p1(N):
       if N < 10:
          raise ValorMuyPequeno("VALOR MUY PEQUEÑO")
       elif N> 50:
          raise ValorMuyGrande("VALOR MUY GRANDE")
       else:
          print(N)
```

Para el segundo punto he hecho esto pero no de resultado y que solo me devuelve la excepcion valor muy pequeño o muy grande

```
       N=2.9
       def p1(N):
          try:
             if N < 10:
                raise ValorMuyPequeno("VALOR MUY PEQUEÑO")
             elif N> 50:
                raise ValorMuyGrande("VALOR MUY GRANDE")
             elif N!=int:
                raise TypeError
             else:
                print(N)
         
          except TypeError:
             print("No es entero")
```

Como puedo hacer para que detecte si es entero o no y salga por pantalla,lo que he hecho sería correcto?  Es necesario usar Try?

Comment: antes de comprobar si es menor o mayor, deberias comprobar si es un numero, no? ;)

Comment: cual es el error que te manda? ya que como lo tienes deberia funcionarte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Para el segundo punto, tal como comentó `gbianchi` es importante comprobar si el valor que entra a la función es de tipo entero o no, para eso puedes utilizar [`isinstance`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_isinstance.asp).

Otro problema es que en el enunciado de tu ejercicio te pide "crear" dos excepciones pero como no has declarado `ValorMuyPequeno` te va a aparecer el error:

```
NameError: name 'ValorMuyPequeno' is not defined
```

Por lo que primero hay que crear esas excepciones, para eso puedes utilizar clases

```
class MuyAlto(Exception):
    pass

class MuyBajo(Exception):
    pass
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
class MuyAlto(Exception):
    pass

class MuyBajo(Exception):
    pass

def p1(N):
    if isinstance(N, int):
        if N < 10:
            raise MuyBajo("VALOR MUY PEQUEÑO")
        elif N> 50:
            raise MuyAlto("VALOR MUY GRANDE")
        else:
            print(N)
    else:
        raise TypeError('La variable no es de tipo entero')
```

Esto devuelve:

```
[In:] p1(5)
[Out:] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MuyBajo                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [28], in <cell line: 18>()
     15     else:
     16         raise TypeError('La variable no es de tipo entero')
---> 18 p1(5)

Input In [28], in p1(N)
      8 if isinstance(N, int):
      9     if N < 10:
---> 10         raise MuyBajo("VALOR MUY PEQUEÑO")
     11     elif N> 50:
     12         raise MuyAlto("VALOR MUY GRANDE")

MuyBajo: VALOR MUY PEQUEÑO

[In:] p1(80)
[Out:] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MuyAlto                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [29], in <cell line: 18>()
     15     else:
     16         raise TypeError('La variable no es de tipo entero')
---> 18 p1(80)

Input In [29], in p1(N)
     10     raise MuyBajo("VALOR MUY PEQUEÑO")
     11 elif N> 50:
---> 12     raise MuyAlto("VALOR MUY GRANDE")
     13 else:
     14     print(N)

MuyAlto: VALOR MUY GRANDE

[In:] p1('9')
[Out:] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [30], in <cell line: 18>()
     15     else:
     16         raise TypeError('La variable no es de tipo entero')
---> 18 p1('9')

Input In [30], in p1(N)
     14         print(N)
     15 else:
---> 16     raise TypeError('La variable no es de tipo entero')

TypeError: La variable no es de tipo entero

[In:] p1(22)
[Out:] 22
```

Comment: Correcto! , muchas gracias!

Comment: Y si se tuviera que hacer con try y except como se haría?